# Either my CPU, motherboard or PSU is bad. Which one is it?

Tags: hard-drive, cpu, motherboard, power-supply, desktop-computer

I've asked a question here before, in December 2013, about a hard drive I wasn't sure whether it was bad. Turns out it was just a side effect from a bigger problem. Symptom: It started with Windows 7 freezing from time to time. This is a different kind of freeze: you can move the mouse and some buttons respond, but things don't open or do what they should. After some time, everything you clicked all respond at once and it goes back to normal. After a few minutes, the process repeats.

Also, the HD's performance starts to degrade. HD Tune, running on the HD, shows a very bad graph. If I leave the computer off for a few minutes, and then run HD Tune from a live CD, the graph looks quite normal. If I insist on using Windows, the performance will continue to degrade up to the point where the HD will no longer be recognized. If I mess around a bit, it will be recognized again. If I immediately reinstall Windows, everything will work normally again, for about two weeks. This happened on several reinstalls. Recently, it started to take about a week, and then less, for the problem to appear.

First, because of some error messages, I suspected the GPU. Removed it, reinstalled Windows, and the problem came back two weeks later. I checked the RAM: nothing. Because the most impacted was the HD (which was the new one I had to buy, because the old one was dead for good), I switched the cables and the ports: nothing. I updated the BIOS and reinstalled Windows: nothing. I checked the temperatures and the voltages, and all seems ok. CMOS battery ok. Visual inspection of the motherboard doesn't reveal anything bad. I clean off the dust every six months (it gets quite dusty in that time).

My specs:

- Biostar H61MLC Version 6.1 (http://www.biostar.com.tw/app/en/mb/introduction.php?S_ID=549)
- Intel® Core™ i3-2100 Processor (http://ark.intel.com/products/53422)
- XTR133D3/4GB, one stick of 4 GB DDR3 RAM
- 350 W C3 Tech PSU

So, which one do I have to replace? The CPU, the mobo, or the PSU?

Comment: Just out of general experience, the processor is probably the least likely candidate. The symptoms you describe make it sound like an HDD or controller problem. Since you've replaced the HDD, I'd guess the issue is the controller, hence, the motherboard. Unfortunately it isn't a cheap/easy thing to replace for testing much of the time.

Comment: *"If I immediately reinstall Windows, everything will work normally again, for about two weeks"* -- If you really had a hardware issue, then reinstalling the OS should not fix or mask that HW issue.  The problem, if it was actually caused by faulty hardware, should have reappeared immediately after reinstall.  So replacing any HW is not likely to help at all.  If the problem is bad HDD sectors, then you should obtain a S.M.A.R.T. summary of the drive.

Comment: Most likely controller driver issues, a corrupt filesystem or remote drives with bad connections (they tend to freeze all IO operations).

Comment: @sawdust If the problem is not HW, I can't understand how it can be SW. Forgot to say: S.M.A.R.T. shows two yellowed items, but overall health is ok. HDAT2 shows no bad sectors.

Comment: @Johannes H. If by remote drive you mean my secondary drive, which I use for data only, I don't think that's the problem. I also got it checked and all tests shows no problems, and it never misbehaved as well.

Comment: By "remote drive" I mean any drives connected by network. Either SMB network drives, or any drives cloud-storage software or for example sshfs provide.

Comment: @sawdust, corruption can take time to show up. If something is causing corruption on the storage media, a fresh install might work fine until enough gets corrupted to cause problems.

Comment: @MaQleod - So you're guessing that there's a HW corruption mechanism that is so subtle and specific to (repeatably) affect process execution, but not cause visible data corruption, or filesystem corruption (that would be detectable) or corruption of executables (to cause BSODs)?  And you claim this would be the mostly likely cause of the OP's problems without having first ruled out malware?  Just because the original question is "is it A, B or C?", does not mean those could be the only possible answers.

Comment: @GuiRitter - *"I can't understand how it can be SW"* - Are you very knowledgeable about computer HW & SW, and trying to politely argue that it's not a SW issue?  That statement conveys almost zero information since we don't know the range/depth of your "understanding".  Have you considered malware, and the 2 week timeframe is the interval it takes to get re-infected?

Comment: Yeah, I also forgot to say it did corrupted the filesystem a bit. Sometimes it would require a chkdsk, and would find errors. It happened, but less frequently, that an important Windows file would be corrupt and it wouldn't boot anymore. Also, I had very few BSODs, but I'm not positive all were related to this problem. It can't possibly be malware, as I'm very careful. Speaking of which, I 've first used a computer ~18 years ago and I've been studying computer engineering for 4 years. When I said I can't understand how it can be SW, I really do not know, because there's a lot I don't know.

Comment: That's enough. I'll buy a new mobo today. And I'll choose a good reputation brand. If I'm lucky, I'll be back here in 3 weeks saying "no problems so far". Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I bought a GIGABYTE GA-H61M-S1. My jaw dropped when I saw the BIOS config screen. First time I see graphics there. Everything looks fine, except it's a bit sluggish sometimes, but I think it's because the HD has suffered a bit too much on the old system. On the first post, I mentioned I had removed the GPU. A few weeks after that, I reinserted it on the old mobo and it failed to send video signal on the BIOS screen. I suspected the old mobo had screwed with it. This friday (Feb 07) I was bored and decided to test the GPU on the new mobo. It worked! Another evidence the old mobo was bad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your voltages are normal and you replaced your hard drive then its the motherboard.  In addition, Biostar doesn't have a good reputation.  All the Biostar motherboard I have had the misfortune of helping other people with are crap.  Get an ASUS motherboard then you will have a rock solid board from a leading company.

Comment: It was the motherboard. February 5th I bought a new mobo and left the old one for testing. Today I went to the same shop to buy a headset and the owner told me the old mobo was showing all sorts of failures, to the point of bricking a processor! He said it's the first damaged processor of its generation that he had seen. He sent it to warranty and hopefully he'll get a new one for free.

Answer (score 0):

Some testing/troubleshooting suggestions:

1. PSU - Get a PSU tester. Or if you have a multimeter, perform a manual test. If performing a manual test, I would [read this guide](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/ht/power-supply-test-multimeter.htm) before attempting.
2. CPU/Mobo/RAM: Get a live CD such as [Inquisitor](http://www.inquisitor.ru/about/) to stress-test your computer. If nothing is found, then it becomes harder to troubleshoot issues such as this. You mentioned you tested RAM, but not the methodology. I prefer using something like [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) and letting at least 2 tests complete. But Inquisitor has you covered on this one too.
3. HDD - For simple tests, download the HDD manufacturer's testing tool. But it looks as if Inquisitor has a built-in test.

Hope some of this helps.

Comment: I've ran two passes on Memtest and all is ok. I've booted Inquisitor 3.0 x64 and, after selecting "Hardware Check", the screen went blank (monitor still receiving video signal), the CD doesn't seem to be spinning and the HD led is dimly lit. According to screenshots, It shouldn't do nothing before another input from me, so I'll reboot and try to make this live CD work.

Comment: Performed a manual test with a multimeter. I wanted to do this before, but it took a while to realize I can reach the pins from the back side of the connector. The −12 V pin was reading −11,3 V. Seems to be within tolerance. I also managed to run Inquisitor 3.1 x86. I ran the non-destructive loop, but I couldn't understand the test results properly. At least I didn't find any mention of errors.